# PHP: Limits when Counting with float values

Tags: php, floating-point, precision

I need to count numbers but have to use a float datatype (don't as why - it's kind of an embedded system).

The simple counter goes like:

```
$num=1.0;
do {
    $num = $num + 1;
    // do some stuff
    // ...
} while (...);
```

Question 1: What is the biggest number that can be counted correctly using a 32-bit and a 64-bit PHP system?

Question 2: When `$num` is read from a MySQL database using a standard FLOAT type (no precision specified) at the beginning of the loop and stored back at the end of the loop, is the answer to Question 1 still valid?

Comment: Do you mean the maximum before you lose precision so that `$num+1` doesn't change the value?

Comment: PHP uses double-precision floating point whether it's a 32-bit or 64-bit system. The bit size only affects integer sizes.

Comment: Double precision has a 52-bit mantissa.

Comment: Yes, excactly: When doesn't change ```$num+1```anymore? What's the exact number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses double precision floating point, which has a 52-bit mantissa. This means that integers represented using floats start losing precision when they reach 2<sup>53</sup> (the extra bit of precision is because the leading bit of a normalized mantissa is always 1, so this doesn't need to be included explicitly in the representation). The following example demonstrates this:

```
echo number_format(pow(2.0, 53)-1) . "<br>" . 
     number_format(pow(2.0, 53)) . "<br>" .  
     number_format(pow(2.0, 53)+1);
```

outputs:

```
9,007,199,254,740,991
9,007,199,254,740,992
9,007,199,254,740,992
```

To get equivalent floating point precision in MySQL you should use the `DOUBLE` datatype, which is 64-bit floating point. If you just use `FLOAT` you'll get 32-bit single precision, which only has 23 bits of mantissa, and loses integer precision at 16,777,216.

See [FLOAT and DOUBLE Data Type Representation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/floating-point-types.html) for more details about how MySQL stores floating point internally.

Comment: Thanks, perfect. Can you address my second question, too, please?

Comment: How PHP processes floats doesn't depend on where it came from. A float is a float.

Comment: ok, but does MySQL use the same float precision as PHP and is there no precision loss while saving and retrieving floats from MySQL?